# "past end of life" or "passed end of life" or both

Tags: grammaticality

I think it is proper to say software *has passed* end of life, however I've also seen it written as *is past* end of life, or for example OpenSSL 1.0.2 (past end of life).

*"past end of life"* has 321k hits on google.

*"passed end of life"* has 6k hits on google.

If they are both correct which would you use and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key term here is *end of life*, because it refers to the end of the maintenance period for software. When something is no longer supported, it is *past* **end of life**. As your research has shown, that is the customary phrase. To say that something has "passed" **end of life** is much less common, and is usually a response to a question. However, the phrase *past end of life* has become a set phrase in software development.

https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/end-of-life

> Hardware or software that is no longer manufactured or supported. An end of life
> announcement by a vendor stipulates when the manufacturing will end, or if already
> ended, how far into the future support for the product will be provided.

You can see examples of "past end of life" in the wild here:

https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/release-support-lifecycle

> Support Past End of Life
>
> It is very important for customers to upgrade to newer, fully supported releases periodically.